# Trying to make a simple login page and Valid () method not running on clicking the button

Tags: android

Here's my code,it takes the username and password from the user and checks with default strings in the `Valid()` method.  The app does not crash instead it does not react to the button activity.

```
package com.example.android.login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText username;
private EditText Password;

private Button Login;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);

    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);


    final String  Username = username.getText().toString();
    final String  password = Password.getText().toString();
    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Valid(Username, password);// This is the function that is not being called on clicking the button
        }
     }) ;
}

public void Valid(String Username, String password) {
    if ((Username.equals("Admin")) && (password.equals("1234"))) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.android.login.userPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: post xml as well

Comment: you are setting Username and password outside click Listener, you need to set these in onClick method

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gain the Username , password inside the `onClickListner`.

```
Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final String  Username = username.getText().toString();
        final String  password = Password.getText().toString();
        Valid(Username, password);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are getting value at initial stage which always blank  rather then getting value in `onCreate` just fetch value every time when click event fire

Try this

```
private EditText username;
private EditText Password;

private Button Login;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);

    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);

    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String  Username = username.getText().toString();
            final String  password = Password.getText().toString();
            Valid(Username, password);// This is the function that is not being called on clicking the button
        }
     }) ;
}

public void Valid(String Username, String password) {
    if ((Username.equals("Admin")) && (password.equals("1234"))) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.android.login.userPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```